# Eclipse not auto compiling modified java files

Tags: java, eclipse, file, compilation

I am having issues with my eclipse where when I change any of the .java files, eclipse does'nt auto compile the modified files. Everytime I have to do a maven install & create a new jar for changes to take effect. This problem is occurring on a regular basis & it sometimes seems to work.

Comment: Try Project > Clean?

Comment: Can you confirm if Project -> Build Automatically is selected?

Comment: For this project, is *Maven* supposed to kick off the compiling, or Eclipse with its own internal compiler?

Comment: Yes, Build Automatically is selected.

Comment: How do I know if Maven is supposed to kick off compiling for modified files for this project? Everything was working normally until yesterday when it suddenly stopped working.